# How can i filter more than 1 column at datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter, dataset, bindingsource

I use this working code to search from textbox any partial word but just **inside one column** (Firstname) and return the filtered result inside `DataGridView`:

```
  ContactsTableBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", "Firstname", TextBox1.Text)
```

How can I search inside others columns?? I've tried some codes like this:

```
  ContactsTableBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", "Firstname" OR ContactsTableBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", "Lastname", TextBox1.Text)
```

```
  ContactsTableBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", "Firstname" OR "Lastname", TextBox1.Text)
```

But doesn't works!
Can anybody show me which is the correct syntax to search **any partial word** at any column?

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and go to the Tools Menu->Options->Projects and Solutions->VB Defaults settings page.  Set Option Strict On as the default for new projects.  To Fix existing projects, Project Menu->"Proj Name"Properties->Compile Tab and set Option Strict On.  Why?  Because then VS will clue you in to bad type operations such as you have shown above and you can then read the documentation on how to fix those errors yourself.  Option Strict Off tells the compiler to do anything it can possibly do to make your code compile even though the result is often wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Boolean expression is actually allowed inside `Filter` property. Example:

```
String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{2}%' OR {1} LIKE '%{2}%'", "Firstname", "Lastname", TextBox1.Text)
```